# Unit test explorer in VS 2012

Tags: c#-4.0

I was using Visual NUnit with VS 2010 to run the specflow tests which worked fine. I recently installed VS 2012 and installed specflow Version 1.9. But I can't find the Unit test explorer option anywhere(in View->Other Windows). Also I can't locate Visual NUnit in the Online

Answer (score 1):

Just start typing `Test` in the Quick Launch box in the upper-right corner.

Alternatively, click Text, Windows, Test Explorer.